# Example of typeahead.js using mongoose for the source - download working code?

Tags: typeahead.js

Can anyone point me to a working example of typeahead.js using mongoose as the data source? All of the examples I have found are just snippets of code that leave out some of what is needed. I have mongoDB and mongoose working in a node.js/express project for a RESTfull API. I just need the complete project (*for dummies*).